# All Virtual Hosts go to first entry

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I have a few domains that look exactly like this in my virtual hosts config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin myemail@gmail.com
     ServerName www.adamzwakk.com
     ServerAlias www.adamzwakk.com
     DocumentRoot /srv/www/adamzwakk
</VirtualHost>
```

Every site after this entry points to this entry (the first one).

Comment: What do the other entries look like? They all have different servername/alias and document root, right?

Comment: Yes they do, they are exact except different DocumentRoot, ServerName, and ServerAlias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it, I put the document paths in quotes and it fixed it.